# JQuery disable keypress code if text is highlighted

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

I have this code so that when users press a key on the keyboard it redirects to pages. There's a lot of them but here's an idea:

```
$('body').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if ( $("*:focus").is("textarea, input") ) return;
    if(event.keyCode==66){ window.location = "page1.php"; }
    if(event.keyCode==71){ window.location = "page2.php"; }
    });
```

What i'm trying to do is make it so that it doesn't redirect if they have text highlighted (as in to copy / paste / whatever). It's annoying when they want to copy text it triggers the C keypress redirect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether `event.ctrlKey` is true. It will signal whether the user is holding the control key while pressing the key or not.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sHHNN/)